# Mongo function updateOne doesn't update the field it's suppose to update

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I run updateOne function inside a PUT request on the server, and apparently the function does not find the record, although it returns no error. The update does not happen.

Premises: I get an id field (not _id) inside the http request. The id is of the form `<name>-stage-###`. I want to change the value of the id to the same without the `-stage-###` part.
So I now have 2 strings: issueId which includes the 'stage' part, and bareIssue which does not.
I delete without checking the record with id = bareIssue (if it exists, it is deleted, and this part works fine).
Then I try to update the id field of the record with `id=issueId`, and change it to bareIssue. This does not work.

Other things that do not work:

- adding or removing quotes from around the `"id"` or id field don't change anything
- putting the $eq modifier in the query phrase doesn't change anything
- Changing the id that I'm searching for to an id that does not exist doesn't change anything, in other words, if I try `updateOne({id:"BLABLABLAFOOBAR"}, {$set: {id:"NiceID"}})`, I still get success in the .then clause of updateOne.
- adding a function to the updateOne and checking for error never gives an error.
- Trying to use mongo ID instead of a string as the id doesn't work.

```
const dbConnection = mongoose.createConnection(DbServerLocation, options);
const db = dbConnection.useDb('issuesAndFiles');
const issuesModel = db.model(ISSUES_COLLECTION_NAME, reportSchema, ISSUES_COLLECTION_NAME);  // In short - it is a model


router.put('/', (req, res, next) => {
    let issueId = req.query['id'];
    if (issueId) {
        let bareIssue = issueId.substring(0, issueId.indexOf("-stage-"));
        issuesModel.findOneAndRemove({id:bareIssue}).then(() => {
            const query = {$eq: {id:issueId}};
            const subst = {$set :{id:bareIssue}};
            let retval = issuesModel.updateOne(query, subst)
                .then(() => {
                    console.log("Put: success in updateOne");
                    res.status(200).send("Approved")
                }
                )
        })
    }
    else {
        res.status(404).send("Issue not specified")
    }
});
```

I expected the document to be updated. It is not.

Comment: `const query = {id: issueId};` not work?

Comment: No it does not work. I have no idea why. It may be something stupid like the .then clause not executing on time or something like this, because from all I can see, it *should* work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to all who tried to help.
My problem was this: my schema did not include the item "id", and it ran in strict mode. Apparently in Robo 3T the schema was updated by someone else, but not in the code. Stupid mistake which took me all day to figure out and fix. Don't let it happen to you:)

Note to people who look for the answer: if you have a variable for the model, such as this:
`const issuesModel = db.model(ISSUES_COLLECTION_NAME, issueSchema, ISSUES_COLLECTION_NAME);` make sure that the `issueSchema` item includes the name that you want to change.

Answer (score 0):

$eq syntax is wrong. Try `{ <field>: { $eq: <value> } }`

Comment: Doesn't work. Also tried simply {<field>:<value>} and didn't work.

Comment: Can someone please tell me how I can parse the return value that I get from the updateOne call?

Comment: catch the error after then(), then you might know the mistake

Comment: I don't get an error on updateOne. When I catch it, it doesn't happen. The updateOne seems to succeed, except that it doesn't change the document.

Comment: More information: When I run the following query on Robo 3T, it succeeds. It's only from the JavaScript code that it (apparently) doesn't work:
```db.getCollection('knownIssues').updateOne({id:"SHMN_12347-stage-001"}, {$set: {id: "SHMN_12347"}})```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this -

```
const dbConnection = mongoose.createConnection(DbServerLocation, options);
const db = dbConnection.useDb('issuesAndFiles');
const issuesModel = db.model(ISSUES_COLLECTION_NAME, reportSchema, ISSUES_COLLECTION_NAME);  // In short - it is a model


router.put('/', (req, res, next) => {
    let issueId = req.query['id'];
    if (issueId) {
        let bareIssue = issueId.substring(0, issueId.indexOf("-stage-"));
        issuesModel.findOneAndRemove({id:bareIssue}).then(() => {
            /* const query = {$eq: {id:issueId}};
            const subst = {$set :{id:bareIssue}}; */

            const query = {id : {$eq: issueId}};
            const subst = {$set :{id:bareIssue}};

            let retval = issuesModel.updateOne(query, subst)
                .then(() => {
                    console.log("Put: success in updateOne");
                    res.status(200).send("Approved")
                }
                )
        })
    }
    else {
        res.status(404).send("Issue not specified")
    }
});
```

Comment: Changed it and it still doesn't work. Any other ideas?